# Setting the value of checkbox to true or false with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a checkbox. With jQuery I would like to set the value of the checkbox to TRUE if checked, and if it is not checked, the value will be set to FALSE. How I can do this please?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**UPDATED**: Using prop instead of attr

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicleChkBox" value="FALSE"/>

 $('#vehicleChkBox').change(function(){
     cb = $(this);
     cb.val(cb.prop('checked'));
 });
```

**OUT OF DATE**:

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYJty/)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicleChkBox" value="FALSE" />

$('#vehicleChkBox').change(function(){
     if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(this).val('TRUE');
     }else{
          $(this).val('FALSE');
     }
});
```

Comment: Old post, but you should now use `.prop('checked')` instead of `attr()`.  Additionally it's easier to force it in one line `var $cb=$(this); $cb.val( $cb.prop('checked'));` or if case is important `var $cb=$(this); $cb.val( ($cb.prop('checked')+'').toUpperCase() );`

Comment: And how to 'uncheck'?

Answer (score 84):

You can do (jQuery 1.6 onwards):

```
$('#idCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('#idCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

to remove you can also use:

```
$('#idCheckbox').removeProp('checked');
```

with jQuery < 1.6 you must do

```
$('#idCheckbox').attr('checked', true);
$('#idCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: But the checkbox value of false won't be submitted with a form submit, right? Is there a way to make that happen

Answer (score 14):

Use `$('#id-of-the-checkbox').prop('checked', true_or_false);`

In case you are using an ancient jQuery version, you'll need to use `.attr('checked', 'checked')` to check and `.removeAttr('checked')` to uncheck.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="FALSE" />
```

jQ:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
  $(this).val(this.checked ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SfEGn/1/)

Please bear in mind that unchecked checkbox will not be submitted in regular form, and you should use hidden filed in order to do it.

Comment: Well, `span` in snippet is for demonstration purposes only and if you take a look at the code, it will be set to be equal to value of checkbox. However, if you need a better (bit faster) solution, this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/SfEGn/130/

Answer (score 4):

```
var checkbox = $( "#checkbox" );
checkbox.val( checkbox[0].checked ? "true" : "false" );
```

This will set the `value` of the checkbox to `"true"` or `"false"` (`value property` is a `string)`, depending whether it's `unchecked` or `checked`.

Works in jQuery >= 1.0

Comment: This is only for the default state of the checkbox. You would need to add an event watcher on the element when the state of the checkbox changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicleChkBox" value="FALSE"/>
```

--

```
$('#vehicleChkBox').change(function(){
    if(this.checked)
        $('#vehicleChkBox').val('TRUE');
   else
        $('#vehicleChkBox').val('False');
});
```

Comment: Please explain your code so that future readers may benefit from it. Thank you