# Changing toggle switch from On to Off or Off to On using if else

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on asp.net MVC 5. I have placed a bootstrap toggle switch button having `input type checkbox`

Bellow is the image of my toggle switch

[image]

From my query i am getting a command name `cmd_Name` in which there is **On** or **Off** value in it and based of this value i just want to change the toggle switch from On-Off or from Off-On

Bellow is my razor syntax for toggle

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//var cmd_Name = Session["cmd_Name"];
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset style="height:60px">
    <legend style="text-align:center;  font-size:large; font-family:'Times New Roman'; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:red">Remote On/Off</legend>
    <input id="test_id" name="cmdName" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">

</fieldset>}
```

Bellow is my script for toggle

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var search = '@Session["search"]';
var cmd_Name = '@Session["cmd_Name"]';
var data = {}
//alert(cmd_Name);
$(window).on('load', function () {

    // here cmd_Name i having On or Off value 

    // i want to put a check like bellow

    if(cmd_Name == "On")
    {
      // then the toggle switch (checkbox) moves to On
     // what should place here that moves the switch from on to off and vise versa
    }
    else
    {
      //then toggle switch (checkbox) moves to Off
    }

})</script>
```

**Updated Code**

Bellow is image for my updated code and error

[image]

**Updated Code 2**

I have following declarations in my `head`section in layout

```
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@*All the javascript and css files that are required by the
    application can be referenced here so that there is no
    need to refrence them in each and every view*@


<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey"></script>


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" /></head>
```

See `bundle.config`

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

I have tried many things in `if...else` like `$("#test_id").checked = true/false` also i have tried `document.getElementById("test_id").checked`

But all in vain, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Now, what is the actual problem? `data` doesn't change? AJAX is not send? Are you sure bootstrap will render the checkbox like you've written it, i.e. is `#test_id` present in the rendered source?

Comment: @Teemu the .on("change") event is working only when the switch is changed from On to Off or Off to On and then in ajax it's passing data and search(serial number) and in controller i have placed a insert query and it's insert data into database

Comment: @Teemu then a fetch query is placed from which i have carried out the command name (cmd_Name) and then stored in a session variable and then passed this variable in my JavaScript. Here i just want to change the switch based command name value

Comment: @Teemu please look into the if..else part right after window on load

Comment: It's still bit unclear what you're asking. `window.onload` is supposed to be executed only once. If you want to change the value of `cmd_Name`, you've to do it in the `onchange` handler, or in the callback of `AJAX` call, as `cmd_Name` being global. Notice, that everything you say you've tried, refers to `#test_id`, not to `cmd_Name`, and now it appears, that the problem is with `cmd_Name`. That's why the question is so confusing.

Comment: @Teemu there is a search functionality which searches the particular serial number and the page is refreshed when clicking on a button and based on that serial number the command name is fetched from the query and using that command name i want to change the switch value

Comment: @Teemu also see the updated question

Comment: If you uncomment `alert(cmd_Name);`, what does it show you? Check also the length of the variable, just in case of leading/trailing white-space characters.

Comment: @Teemu it will show me the current value of 'cmd_Name' and the length is okay i have checked it

Comment: @Teemu don't get confuse with the test_id, i simply want to move the switch to respective value if it's On then it remains at On if it's Off then it's shift to Off

Comment: Back to my first comment then,  is `#test_id` present in the source? And is it the same element you really see on the screen? Have you taken a look at the console, there might be some error messages?

Comment: `$("#test_id").is(":checked")` should work. What's the issue with that?

Comment: @Teemu There are no errors in console and `test_id` is id

Comment: @Akshay Yes `$("#test_id").is(":checked")` is working but it's for my `onChange` event i just simply want to change the value of switch button from On to Off or Off to On based on `cmd_Name`

Comment: @Akshay as per you answer i have tried but get an error. also see the update code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
if(cmd_Name == "On") {
    $("#test_id").attr("checked", "checked");
} else if(cmd_Name == "Off") {
   $("#test_id").removeAttr("checked");
}
```

You can do it this way as well

```
if(cmd_Name == "On") {
    $("#test_id").bootstrapToggle("on")
} else if(cmd_Name == "Off") {
   $("#test_id").bootstrapToggle("off")
}
```

Comment: For both i am getting same error 
`error CS0103: The name '$' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: That means you need to add reference to jquery

Comment: jquery is in my layout and the toggle code is in my partial view

Comment: The error you got comes if you haven't included jquery or you are executing your code before it gets loaded. Also make sure that you are not loading jquery twice

Comment: So what to do in that case ? I can't add jquey reference in my partial view as it will conflict the reference in layout

Comment: Include your reference in `head` in layout

Comment: I have added the toggle code and script in my layout where there is the reference for jquery but still i am getting the same error, and all of my references are in the head section

Comment: Make sure jquery in not loaded from a bundle. Check your bundle.config

Comment: Kindly see my **Updated Code 2**

Comment: I can see that you have added jquery reference in bundle as well as layout. Are you referencing that bundle somewhere in layout?

Comment: No there is not bundle reference in my layout

Comment: Not sure what's wrong but the references seems to be conflicting or missing somewhere. It is hard to tell without looking into the code.

Comment: My change function and all other javascript functions which contains `$` in them are working well and giving results, i don't know what is the problem in toggle case

Comment: Write your code in `$(document).ready(function(){})` instead of `window.load`

Comment: I am following all the links 
[https://www.tunnelsup.com/jquery-checkbox-checked-reading-and-setting/], 
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/8328125/6856823] [http://www.electrictoolbox.com/check-uncheck-checkbox-jquery/]

Many other links as well but still unable to do my task :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124640/discussion-between-akshay-and-fasi).