# Asp.net MVC check/uncheck the checkbox based on a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on asp.net MVC 5, i have added a `bootstrap toggle switch` of type `checkbox` in `input` field like bellow

```
 <input id="test_id" name="cmdName" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

I want to do Check/Uncheck the checkbox based on **On** or **Off** value

**Note:** By default it's always on

I want to do something like this in my Javascript

```
If(command == "On")
{
  //then it will check the checkbox
}
else if (command =="Off")
{
  //then it will uncheck the checkbox     
}
```

I have found many similar questions related to it and I tried to implement it but all in vain

The links are bellow

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17420580/6856823)
2. [Link 2](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/)
3. [Link 3](http://www.webknowledgefree.com/check-uncheck-checkbox-using-jquery/)
4. [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8328125/6856823)

Also i have tried to add `$('input:checkbox[name=cmdName]').attr('checked', false);` including `setAttribute` , `removeAttribute` , `.prop` and many others, but couldn't accomplished the task and i don't know what is the problem

I am using `jquery 3.1.0` and bellow are my references

```
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@*All the javascript and css files that are required by the
    application can be referenced here so that there is no
    need to refrence them in each and every view*@


<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey"></script>


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" /></head>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Check out [THIS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p18t9hcs/1/).

I used jquery 3.1.0 and Chrome to test it.

```
$("#toggler").on("click", function() {
    var state = $('#myCheckbox').prop("checked");
    if (!state)
        $('#myCheckbox').prop("checked", true);
    else
        $('#myCheckbox').prop("checked", false);
});
```

Comment: I am using both jquery 3.1.0 and chrome and also used the .prop but no use

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the console for any errors? I'd say the order of your scripts is wrong. Try including the `bootstrap-toggle.js` script after the `bootstrap.min.js`.

If there are no errors, try toggling the checkbox like this:

```
$('#test_id').bootstrapToggle('on')
```

Or

```
$('#test_id').bootstrapToggle('off')
```

Comment: I added the methods used to set the state of the checkbox, give it a try.