# How change state of CheckBox in browser console?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I just want to change value of CheckBox with JavaScript in browser console.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="333521" class="checkboxNice" onchange="highlitParts(this)">
```

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript

Comment: I think this is what your looking for! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328033/setting-the-value-of-checkbox-to-true-or-false-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

How I made that:

```
document.getElementsByName("checkbox[]", 333521)[0].checked = true
```